# Clustering values by their proximity in python (machine learning?)

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I have an algorithm that is running on a set of objects. This algorithm produces a score value that dictates the differences between the elements in the set.

The sorted output is something like this:

[1,1,5,6,1,5,10,22,23,23,50,51,51,52,100,112,130,500,512,600,12000,12230]

If you lay these values down on a spreadsheet you see that they make up groups

[1,1,5,6,1,5] [10,22,23,23] [50,51,51,52] [100,112,130] [500,512,600] [12000,12230]

Is there a way to programatically get those groupings?

Maybe some clustering algorithm using a machine learning library? Or am I overthinking this?

I've looked at scikit but their examples are way too advanced for my problem...

Answer (score 41):

## Don't use clustering for 1-dimensional data

Clustering algorithms are designed for multivariate data. When you have 1-dimensional data, **sort** it, and look for the **largest gaps**. This is trivial and *fast* in 1d, and not possible in 2d. If you want something more advanced, use Kernel Density Estimation (KDE) and look for local minima to split the data set.

There are a number of duplicates of this question:

- [1D Number Array Clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513484/1d-number-array-clustering)
- [Cluster one-dimensional data optimally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869609/cluster-one-dimensional-data-optimally)

Comment: This approach might be sensitive to noise.

Comment: On the contrary. KDE is smooth and thus not too sensitive to noise. Much less so than k-means which is known to be very sensitive due to squared error terms.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: What does "largest" mean in this context? If I have a list of gaps, how do I find those that constitute a large enough gap to separate "clusters"?

Answer (score 29):

A good option if you don't know the number of clusters is `MeanShift`:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth

x = [1,1,5,6,1,5,10,22,23,23,50,51,51,52,100,112,130,500,512,600,12000,12230]

X = np.array(zip(x,np.zeros(len(x))), dtype=np.int)
bandwidth = estimate_bandwidth(X, quantile=0.1)
ms = MeanShift(bandwidth=bandwidth, bin_seeding=True)
ms.fit(X)
labels = ms.labels_
cluster_centers = ms.cluster_centers_

labels_unique = np.unique(labels)
n_clusters_ = len(labels_unique)

for k in range(n_clusters_):
    my_members = labels == k
    print "cluster {0}: {1}".format(k, X[my_members, 0])
```

Output for this algorithm:

```
cluster 0: [ 1  1  5  6  1  5 10 22 23 23 50 51 51 52]
cluster 1: [100 112 130]
cluster 2: [500 512]
cluster 3: [12000]
cluster 4: [12230]
cluster 5: [600]
```

Modifying `quantile`variable you can change the clustering number selection criteria

Comment: The first argument of `np.array` needs to be `list(zip(x,np.zeros(len(x))))`. Otherwise, Python throws an error: _TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'zip'_

Comment: This approach may not work very well for some inputs that aren't easily "clusterable", e.g. `x = [90, 100, 110]`. It will then fail with `ValueError: Expected n_neighbors > 0. Got 0` (which can be avoided with parameter tuning). For such inputs https://stackoverflow.com/a/18385795/942774 is probably the much simpler and better answer.

Comment: I replaced `X = np.array(zip(x,np.zeros(len(x))), dtype=np.int)` with `X = np.array(x).reshape(-1, 1)` and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

You can use clustering to group these. The trick is to understand that there are two dimensions to your data: the dimension you can see, and the "spatial" dimension that looks like [1, 2, 3... 22]. You can create this matrix in [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) like so:

```
import numpy as np

y = [1,1,5,6,1,5,10,22,23,23,50,51,51,52,100,112,130,500,512,600,12000,12230]
x = range(len(y))
m = np.matrix([x, y]).transpose()
```

Then you can perform clustering on the matrix, with:

```
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans
kclust = kmeans(m, 5)
```

kclust's output will look like this:

```
(array([[   11,    51],
       [   15,   114],
       [   20, 12115],
       [    4,     9],
       [   18,   537]]), 21.545126372346271)
```

For you, the most interesting part is the first column of the matrix, which says what the centers are along that x dimension:

```
kclust[0][:, 0]
# [20 18 15  4 11]
```

You can then assign your points to a cluster based on which of the five centers they are closest to:

```
assigned_clusters = [abs(cluster_indices - e).argmin() for e in x]
# [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: an updated function kmeans2 (in scipy.cluster.vq) now outputs both centroid and label, e.g. `kclust, label = kmeans(m, 5)`

Comment: Hi,
The code does not work. Error in first line for obvious reasons. The last line also produces an error, 'cluster_indices' not defined.
Can you please help to get this code running ?

Comment: @gprakhar Use `cluster_indices = kclust[0][:, 0]`.

Comment: I think last line should be 

assigned_clusters = [abs(kclust[0][:, 0]- e).argmin() for e in y]

N.b. second to last character is changed to y