# Python, error sklearn

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

Im trying to run the first answer to the question in this thread:

[Clustering values by their proximity in python (machine learning?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364026/clustering-values-by-their-proximity-in-python-machine-learning)

my goal is to cluster a set of 1D data, but i run into the error saying:

```
Import error: cannot import name  __check_build
```

is there a chance that the package was not downloaded properly?

im using pip and windows 64 bit

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274696/importerror-in-importing-from-sklearn-cannot-import-name-check-build

Comment: i am unable to download scipy as well , so this wont work @idjaw