# Given a set of bounding boxes in an 2D space, group them into rows

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

Given a set of **N** bounding boxes with vertex coordinates:

```
"vertices": [
    {
      "y": 486, 
      "x": 336
    }, 
    {
      "y": 486, 
      "x": 2235
    }, 
    {
      "y": 3393, 
      "x": 2235
    }, 
    {
      "y": 3393, 
      "x": 336
    }
  ]
```

I would like to group the bounding boxes into rows. In other words, given the pictorial representation of bounding boxes in this image:

[image: Bounding Boxes]

I would like an algorithm that returns:

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8]
```

[Edit: Clarification] The grouping decisions (e.g. [4,5,6] and [7,8]) should be based on some kind of error minimisation such as least squares.

Is there an algorithm or library (preferably in python) that does this?

Comment: You can draw a horizontal line under (1,2,3) that doesn't cut through any boxes, so (1,2,3) are seperate. However, you can't split (4,5,6,7,8) in that way. So how do you define the choice of (4,5,6) (7,8) and not e.g. (5,6) (4,8) (7) ?

Comment: Ah I should have clarified - I framed the problem that way so that the algorithm would have to be use some kind of least-squares error optimisation (or an alternative). The bounding boxes won't always be clearly separable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a clustering problem. In fact, because you can ignore the x co-ordinates, I think this is a 1-dimensional clustering problem. Some standard clustering algorithms such as k-means are good for minimising sums of squares from cluster centres, which amounts to what you are looking for. Unfortunately, they don't guarantee to find the globally best solution. One-dimensional clustering is a special case for which there are exact algorithms - see [Cluster one-dimensional data optimally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869609/cluster-one-dimensional-data-optimally).

Comment: Wouldn't 1D clustering lump (4,5,6,7,8) together?

Comment: With clustering you usually tell it the number of different clusters to divide the points into so whether it groups any set of points together will depend on the number of clusters you ask for. Alternatively you can create a penalty that rises with the number of clusters created and find the solution that gives the best total of penalty and sum of squared deviations. Then you try and find a penalty system that gets you the sort of divisions you want.

Comment: I think that in this particular problem, ignoring the x-coordinate would create worse results; in the example, the fact that (4,5,6) (7,8) is a better split than (5,6) (4,7,8) only becomes apparent if you know that 4 and 7 overlap horizontally. (Unless the penalty system can re-introduce the x-coordinate.)

Comment: mmm, ok clustering with a penalty function does seem like the correct classification for this problem. There are some nuances to the dimensionality and how to pick the x/y coordinate that best represents each box, i.e. should it be just an average of the coordinates (regardless of 1-D or 2-D)? but alright, I'll accept this answer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I didn't quote a sample penalty function because clustering books typically don't commit themselves, but one option to try comes from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#Comparison_with_least_squares: AIC = 2k + n ln(RSS). Here k is the number of clusters (since you have one parameter per cluster - the x co-ordinate) n is the number of data points, and RSS is the sum of squared errors, or sum of squared deviations from the nearest cluster centre. So you could take AIC as the resulting penalty function.

Answer (score 1):

As an example of clustering these rectangles, lets just cluster them by incrementally merging the most heavily overlapping clusters repeatedly.

First, lets define our rectangle, in code:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Rect:
    label: str
    x: int
    y: int
    width: int
    height: int
```

Next, lets turn these rectangles into overlapping intervals, so we can quickly query for which ones overlap. We'll discard the `x` coordinate, since its completely useless to us, rename `width` to `density` since we're now working in 1D, and replace `height` with a computed `end` offset.

```py
@dataclass
class Interval:
    start: int
    end: int
    density: int

    label: str

    @classmethod
    def from_rect(cls, rect):
        return cls(rect.y, rect.y + rect.height, rect.width, rect.label)

    def overlap_weight(self, target):
        start = max(self.start, target.start)
        end = min(self.end, target.end)

        value = (end - start) * (self.density + target.density)
        return value
```

Now, to find the overlaps between intervals, we use a standard O(n log n) approach of sorting the start/end points and keeping a running record of current intervals.

```py
def find_overlaps(intervals):
    array = []

    for idx, interval in enumerate(intervals):
        array.append((interval.start, 1, idx))
        array.append((interval.end, 0, idx))
    
    array.sort()

    overlaps = []
    indices = set()

    for _, is_start, idx in array:
        if is_start:
            overlaps.extend((intervals[idx], intervals[i]) for i in indices)
            indices.add(idx)
        else:
            indices.discard(idx)

    return overlaps
```

Now, we'll want to take our overlaps, and represent this in a graph, as edges between vertices representing our interval clusters. The edge weight will be our our combined interval overlap weights. For this, I'll lean on `networkx` to handle the graph logic.

```py
from networkx import Graph, common_neighbors, neighbors

def make_graph(intervals):
    overlaps = find_overlaps(intervals)

    graph = Graph()
    for interval in intervals:
        graph.add_node(interval.label, intervals=[interval])

    for a, b in overlaps:
        weight = a.overlap_weight(b)
        graph.add_edge(a.label, b.label, weight=weight)

    return graph
```

Then, we want to find the edge with the largest weight (most overlap between two clusters), and merge these two vertices into a new vertex (cluster).

```py
def find_max_edge(graph):
    return max(graph.edges.data("weight"))

def contract_vertices(graph, v1, v2):
    v3 = v1 + ";" + v2
    intervals = graph.nodes[v1]["intervals"] + graph.nodes[v2]["intervals"]

    graph.add_node(v3, intervals=intervals)
    common = set(common_neighbors(graph, v1, v2))

    for v in common:
        w1 = graph.edges[v, v1]["weight"]
        w2 = graph.edges[v, v2]["weight"]
        graph.add_edge(v, v3, weight=w1+w2)

    for v_old in [v1, v2]:
        for v in set(neighbors(graph, v_old)) - common - {v1, v2}:
            weight = graph.edges[v, v_old]["weight"]
            graph.add_edge(v, v3, weight=weight)
        graph.remove_node(v_old)
```

Finally, we can just do this `find_max_edge` and `contract_vertices` in a loop until either we have the desired number of clusters, or the new maximum edge weight (the amount of overlap between out clusters) is below some threshold, and then break out. We then just print out the intervals associated with each vertex (cluster), to see the actual clustering results.

```py
def main():
    test = [
        Rect("1", 10, 10, 100, 75),
        Rect("2", 120, 0, 50, 30),
        Rect("3", 150, 10, 100, 75),

        Rect("4", 50, 120, 50, 25),
        Rect("5", 120, 100, 50, 25),
        Rect("6", 190, 100, 50, 25),

        Rect("7", 0, 165, 175, 20),
        Rect("8", 190, 145, 60, 50),
    ]
    
    intervals = [Interval.from_rect(rect) for rect in test]
    graph = make_graph(intervals)

    while len(graph) > 3:  # break when there's 3 or less clusters
        v1, v2, weight = find_max_edge(graph)
        # you could also break on weight < threshold instead
        contract_vertices(graph, v1, v2)

    for _, intervals in graph.nodes.data("intervals"):
        print([interval.label for interval in intervals])
```

To run the complete script, just paste these code snippets in order into your file (all necessary imports and declarations are included), and call `main()`.

Output:

```py
['7', '8']
['4', '5', '6']
['1', '2', '3']
```